# C++: Template method pattern using directly the derived type

Tags: c++, derived-class, virtual-functions, vtable

Suppose that situation:

```
struct base
{
    void method()
    {
        requisites();

        do_it();
    }

    virtual void requisites() const = 0;
    void do_it() { /* do it */ }
};

struct derived : base
{
    void requisites() const
    {
        if (!my_requisites)
           throw something;
    }
}

int main()
{
    derived d;
    d.method();

    return 0;
}
```

In that case, where I'm not using pointers or references, but directly instances of the derived type, does the compiler need to do a run-time query against the vtable to select the correct override of `requisites` (the one of `derived`)? Or is that kind of behaviour as efficent as using no virtual functions? In other words, does the compiler know in compilation time that we are using `derived::requisites()`?

Comment: This depends heavily on the compiler you are using. Some compilers are smart enough to say, "hey, there's only one class in this entire project that derives from base, so let's just do away with the vtable".

Comment: What does this question have to do with the Strategy pattern?

Comment: @ChristianHackl Sorry, you are right. In any case it would be a "template method" pattern. And you are right again, the question isn't a "design patterns"-related question (although the pattern is used here as the context of the problem)

Answer (score 1):

vtable is not necessarily slower.

For example on x86 in a unix shared object, position independent code has been produced (gcc3, gcc4) using a hack to load ebx with the current eip.  This value was used to find a jump table for any static functions.  Calling a dynamic function could be performed by querying the `this` pointer directly, and was faster (if no static functions were called in a given function).

The compiler does know the concrete type, and is able to call directly the function, but may choose to find the function virtually because :-

a) it may be faster.

b) it simplifies the amount of code generation cases.